# What does "leading coefficient is positive" mean here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Artin Textbook Proposition 12.3.7(a):

**Let f be an integer polynomial with positive leading coefficient. Then f is an irreducible element of Z[x]
if and only if it is either a prime integer or a primitive polynomial that is irreducible in Q[x].**

The proof is divided by cases.

For me, I only do not understand partially.

The question I have is for the case f is non-constant: from the proof given, f has an integer factor different from +1 or -1, since f is irreducible over Z[x], which makes sense. But I do not know "*so if its leading coefficient is positive, it will be primitive*".

I asked my instructor, the feedback is "For a non-constant polynomial, an integer factor need not be +1 or -1. For example, 2x+4 has a factor of 2."

I do not understand what does it means. Anyone could help? Thanks advance.

Note: Regarding the book says: "**If f is irreducible and not constant, it cannot have an integer factor different from +1 or -1, so if its leading coefficient is positive, it will be primitive**".

Comment: Let $f(x)=a_kx^k+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ with $a_k\ne0$.  $\,a_k$ is the *leading coefficient* of $f$

Comment: My question is why leading coefficient of polynomial f is positive, and it is irreducible over Z[x], then it is primitive. This is the proof interpreted from the book.

Comment: What exactly does the book say? Maybe it says if the leading coefficient is $1$ then the polynomial has no integer factor?

Comment: I edited by adding the book says.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense in context but just having a positive leading coefficient doesn't exclude having a prime integer factor.

Comment: What you mean is I overthink about this sentence? Since I always think why it should be here? Is this what you mean? Or else?

Comment: I mean that just going off of what you've posted, the book is wrong. But possibly there is some context to what the book writes that makes it correct.

Comment: Maybe it's just because of differences in the edition of the book, but what you've written for the proof is not at all what I see in my copy. The proof starts by writing $f = c f_0$ where $c$ is a constant (the gcd of the coefficients) and $f_0$ is primitive. Since $f$ is irreducible, this cannot be an actual factorization, so either $c$ or $f$ must be a unit. By the positivity assumption, then either $c = 1$ or $f = 1$. The proof then examines both cases.

Comment: It does make sense to me. Thank you:-)